# How to fix "the monitored command" error?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a program that stores words of a string within the space in an array(For example: If user inputs - "Hello what's up" ,So i want to store Hello, What's,Up in an array of thier respective indices (Hello in 0th index,What's in 1st index and up in 2nd index). I'm using c method of DMA in c++ to achieve this.
Following is my code-
https://code.sololearn.com/cNWxZV9IoG4q/?ref=app

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string sentence;
    getline(cin,sentence);
    stringstream ss(sentence);
    string *words;
    int count=0;
    
    while(ss>>sentence)
    {
     if(count==0)
     {        
   words=
  (string*)malloc((count+1)*sizeof(string));
  *(words+count)=ss.str();
  count++;
  continue;
     }
      words=(string*)realloc(words, (count+1)*sizeof(string));
    *(words+count)=ss.str();
    free(words);
      count++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

But , I'm getting error , Could anyone please fix it?

Comment: Post the code here in your question so that in case the site you linked to breaks, future readers will still be able to see it. Moreover, having code here would make this question more concise.

Comment: Why is this tagged "C++" when you are clearly writing "C"?

Comment: @JesperJuhl It's c++ , I'm just using c style of dynamic memory allocation in c++.

Comment: "I'm just using c style of dynamic memory allocation in c++." That's exactly your problem. `words=(string*)malloc((count+1)*sizeof(string));` You can't do that. C++ is not C. You can't `malloc` a non-trivial C++ class. Please learn how to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Avoid C style constructs in C++ whenever there's a choice.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.As far as i know,We can use malloc,calloc,realloc in c++ 

Comment: C++ objects (such as `std::string`) have constructors. Don't use `malloc` in C++  code.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki As we do not have realloc in c++ style of dynamic memory allocation, That's why I'm using c style of dma.

Comment: @heapunderrun Sorry but can you please explain this again??

Comment: Sure, you *can* use `malloc` in C++, but it doesn't run the constructor of `std::string` for you, which means that the `std::string` objects are not properly initialized in your code.

Comment: @ManavRoy You *can* use C-style allocation in C++ but there’s never a good reason to, *especially* when you don’t know how to use it correctly. — You don’t need `realloc` in C++ if you use C++ properly (e.g. by using vectors or, for low-level code, allocators). And in particular you *can’t* use `realloc` with non-trivial types. It doesn’t work.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki   Sorry for disturbing you , But I'm not getting the term "string object's" ,I think that string is a datatype and not class ,So what does it has to do with objects?

Comment: The `string` in your code refers to `std::string` defined in `<string>` header of the C++ STL. It is not a primitive type but actually a class.

Comment: You are not the first person to try to `realloc` an array of C++ objects "for efficiency", and most certainly not the last one. People coming to C++ from C were trying to do this since C++ was invented. It didn't work back then, and it doesn't work now.

Comment: The memory representation of an `std::string` object typically consists just of some pointers into dynamically allocated memory that `std::string` object manages itself. The class has member functions / operators to assign strings etc., it allocates and manages its internal buffer itself. When you just `malloc` and brutally write at the allocated memory region, you are clobbering `std::string`'s internal pointers (which, by the way, are not even initialized at that point, because the constructor didn't run). This is not the way how C++ is meant to be done.

Comment: I've saw you guys are using the term "constructor of string object" I've a question,Is string a class or object? And what do you mean by string constructor? What's present in string constructor?

Comment: `std::string` is a class (i.e. the type). The class is used to create objects of the type `std::string`. I suggest you to go through some materials on this topic if you want to know more about classes and objects in C++.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki  So ,std::string is a class ,And string variable (string str[str in this case]) is a object of string class?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use C in C++. Just use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to store the words:

```
std::string word;
std::vector<std::string> words;

while (ss >> word) {
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

And then you can print the individual words like so:

```
for (auto& word: words) {
    std::cout << word << '\n';
}
```

Or if you wish to use indices:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i  < words.size(); ++i) {
    std::cout << i << ": " << words[i] << '\n';
}
```

The reason why your code fails is, as @heapunderrun mentioned, the fact that `std::string` has a constructor. If you don't call the constructor in some way, then the string will be in an indeterminate state. When you try to assign to such a string, like in:

```
*(words+count)=ss.str();
```

Then your program will crash. If you really want to use manual memory allocation, then you have to use [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new) and [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/delete). You can use `malloc()` if you really want to, but then you still should use placement `new` to ensure the `std::string` objects are correctly constructed inside the memory you allocated. Finally, you probably can't use `realloc()` safely, you would have to `malloc()` a new array, copy everything properly to the new array, then `free()` the old array.

Comment: I don't wanna use STL ,I wanna use c style of dma here.

Comment: @ManavRoy "I don't wanna use STL ,I wanna use c style of dma here." - Why???

Comment: @JesperJuhl  I've not study STL yet ,Plus I'm weak in DMA , That's why.

Comment: @ManavRoy The issue is that manual memory management in C++ is just a bad idea, you will learn bad coding habits this way. Stick to the STL. If you want to learn manual memory management, I suggest you write some program in pure C.

Comment: As a side note, the term *DMA* usually refers to *direct memory access*, which has nothing to do with heap memory allocation.